# Insert a list into sql query (IN clause)

Tags: java, sql, string

I have a list as follows -

```
List<String> Friends = ImmutableList.of("Ross","Joey","Chandler");
```

And the following query-

```
Select * from EmployeeTable where name IN ('%1$s');
```

I am trying to figure out a way to insert this list into the query using String.format() in JAVA.

I want the query to eventually look like -

```
Select * from EmployeeTable where name IN ('Ross','Joey','Chandler');
```

Please Help me out

Comment: What are you using ? Spring Data ? JPA ? JDBC Template ? Please provide a complete reproducible example

Comment: Actually creating this query for Amazon Athena

Comment: Working on Spring

Comment: Something like `String.format("Select * from EmployeeTable where name IN ('%s');", friends.stream().collect(Collectors.joining( ", ")));` ? Works with Java versions >= 8. Not a MWE with SQL but just an idea.

Comment: @LudovicKuty I tried this. This produces something like - Select * from EmployeeTable where name IN ('Ross,Joey,Chandler');

Comment: Closed as duplicate since you said Spring.

Comment: Added second duplicate link, in case you're using plain JDBC.

Comment: @Andreas I have to do it using String.format only

Comment: @Andreas These links don't answer my question

Comment: You should **never** build a SQL statement using string concatenation of string values that are not guaranteed to be SQL-safe. Since a persons name is entered by a user, it is by nature not SQL-safe.

Comment: Ludovic was on the right track, but got it wrong: `friends.stream().map(n -> "'" + n + "'").collect(Collectors.joining(","))` --- Be aware that this still leaves you vulnerable to SQL syntax errors and SQL injection attacks, where hackers can steal your data and destroy your database.

Comment: @Andreas This produces something like - ```Select * from EmployeeTable where name IN  (' 'Ross','Joey','Chandler' '); There is still an extra single quote at the ends```

Comment: Come on man, at least make an *attempt* at thinking about this for yourself. ***Look at the code!!!*** If the result has extra `'` after `(` and extra `'` before `)`, and you're formatting using `format("Select ... IN ('%s')`, then ...  ... there are extra `'` in there ...  ... perhaps ...  ... removing them might do something ... 

Comment: Oh my, I forgot the `map` operation! Answered too quickly without proper thinking. This little example is a nice way to think about functional programming thanks to that `map`. The remark by @Andreas about string concatenation and SQL is also worth some thinking. I encourage you to spend time on both of those.